# How to reuse a function signature for multiple functions with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the following code:

```js
type TCallBack = () => void

const subscriptions: { [key: string]: TCallBack[] } = {}

interface ISubscription {
  eventName: string
  callback: TCallBack
}

export function unsubscribe({ eventName, callback }: ISubscription) {
  // ...
}

export function subscribe({ eventName, callback }: ISubscription) {
  // ...
}

export function subscribeOnce({ eventName, callback }: ISubscription) {
  // ...
}
```

The function signature `{ eventName, callback }: ISubscription` is used for multiple functions. Is there a way to avoid having to copy this signature but reuse it? I was thinking that something like the below would be great:

```js
const functionSignature = { eventName, callback }: ISubscription
export function subscribe(functionSignature ) {
```

But this of course does not work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why would you want to do a thing like that?It would make your code very inflexible for little or no benefit

Comment: I thought it would avoid duplication of code.

Comment: but it's not really code. It's the function contract and each function should have it's own contract. Trying to do this is going to make your code worse, not better. You're taking "don't repeat yourself" too literally. [Some good advice here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/103235)

Comment: For good advise on all this kind of thing you should reap the seminal ["refactoring" by Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/refactoring-2nd-ed.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a type that determines your input parameters and return type and then just write implementation like this:

```
type TCallBack = () => void

const subscriptions: { [key: string]: TCallBack[] } = {}

interface ISubscription {
  eventName: string
  callback: TCallBack
}

type FunctionType = (subscription: ISubscription) => void

export const unsubscribe: FunctionType = ({ eventName, callback }) => {

}

export const subscribe: FunctionType = ({ eventName, callback }) => {

}

export const subscribeOnce: FunctionType = ({ eventName, callback }) => {

}
```

But as mentioned in comments this isn't very good approach because it doesn't give you much of benefit, but rather cause problems in some refactoring scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,
you could define a type for your function like this:

```
type EventCallBack = () => void

export type SubscribeFunction = (subscription: Subscription) => void

export interface Subscription {
  eventName: string
  callback: EventCallBack
}


export const unsubscribe: SubscribeFunction = ({ eventName, callback }) => {}

...
```

If you go this way I suggest to:

- Export both the `SubscribeFunction` and `Subscription` types, so that a consumer of your module can correctly reference the types
- Use more meaningful, domain-oriented names for your types, that better reflects their purpose; I used `EventCallback` instead of `TCallback`, and removed the useless I prefix from your interface.

Answer (score 0):

### Tl;Dr

don't

---

You seem to be trying to apply [DRY principle here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63408946/how-to-reuse-a-function-signature-for-multiple-functions-with-typescript?noredirect=1#comment112123463_63408946). But I'm going to say that this is inappropriate and you shouldn't attempt to do this at all. The idea behind DRY is to make your code less brittle, so changes to functionality don't need to be made in multiple places.

Ask yourself "how does defining this signature in one place achieve that?"

I'm going to suggest it doesn't and all it does is make your code overly complex and inflexible.

You see function signatures **are not functionality**. They're contracts. Ideally you want each signature to have it's own contract as it lowers the dependencies between blocks of code and allows for more flexible refactoring.

[Here's some good advice:](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/103235)

> However, DRY is often taken to an extreme by clever programmers.
> Sometimes to not repeat yourself you have to create abstractions so
> obtuse that your teammates cannot follow them. Sometimes the structure
> of two things is only vaguely similar but different enough. If
> doStuff1-4 are different enough such that refactoring them to not
> repeat yourself causes you to have to write unnatural code or undergo
> clever coding backflips that will cause your team to glare at you,
> then it may be ok to repeat yourself. I've bent over backwards to not
> repeat myself a couple of times in unnatural ways and regretted the
> end product.

Comment: You're right, I was overthinking this. Thanks for putting me on the right path again.